# Relativelayout check banner ad?

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, ads, banner

I'm showing a banner on the bottom of the screen.

This is the XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutAdView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sometimes I get Ad Request Completed, but I don't see the banner.

How can I check the Relative Layout? If something is showing in the Relative Layout then it should give me true else false.

Comment: no tags in subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Google Admob SDK since you haven't specified which ad server software you are using.

You can attach an AdListener to your ad space on screen and handle what you want to do when add fails to show.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;

public class AdmobAdListener implements AdListener {

    Context context;
    AdRequest adRequest;

    public AdmobAdListener(Context context, AdRequest adRequest) {
        this.context = context;
        this.adRequest = adRequest;
    }

    /** The log tag. */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AdmobAdListener";

    /** Called when an ad is clicked and about to return to the application. */
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDismissScreen");
         Toast.makeText(context, "onDismissScreen",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    /** Called when an ad was not received. */
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, ErrorCode error) {
        String message = LOG_TAG + " onFailedToReceiveAd (" + error + ")";
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ad.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    /**
     * Called when an ad is clicked and going to start a new Activity that will
     * leave the application (e.g. breaking out to the Browser or Maps
     * application).
     */
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onLeaveApplication");
         Toast.makeText(context, "onLeaveApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Called when an Activity is created in front of the app (e.g. an
     * interstitial is shown, or an ad is clicked and launches a new Activity).
     */
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPresentScreen");
         Toast.makeText(context, "onPresentScreen",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /** Called when an ad is received. */
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceiveAd");
         Toast.makeText(context, "onReceiveAd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Using this tag in you layout XML file

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/adMob"
        ads:adUnitId="abcdefghighlmnop123"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Comment: I'm using InMobi + AdMob. AdMob is great. Works perfect. The question was for InMobi.